# Forward facing vector is a bit offset

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am making an FPS game and I need for the forward facing vector to hit exactly where the crosshair is aiming.
[This is my current blueprint.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLaqr.png)

It takes all references from the [camera position where the players head should be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAb99.png) (as it usually is in FPS games).

When "shooting" the vector it is [slightly offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txKkH.png) though. (pink dot near crosshair)

Things I have tried:

1. Increasing distance of vector makes the problem go away but it then becomes inconsistent, which means it's a bad solution to the problem :(
2. Manually changing axis values, but that was also very inconsistent.
3. Changing between 3 different nodes of taking rotation from the camera, they all (didn't) work the same way :/

Maybe there is an issue of the values that I am taking, although the starting position of the camera seems to be correct.

Thank you for any insight you may have!

Comment: Could you include some more specific information about "3 different nodes of taking rotation from the camera"

Comment: Also please include a screenshot of the Components of all involved blueprints and/or how you are assigning to Player Cam Ref. Basically, please include a [mre].

Comment: Player Cam Ref is just a variable that is of camera component object reference added to the same blueprint

Comment: The other node was using get world transform and then get world transform but split up. I think all three ways are of same thing just named differenctly

Comment: Also, is the crosshair actually at the center of the screen? Can't tell from the included screenshot

Comment: That was it, apparently it somehow shifted, the blueprint and all is good it was the crosshair. How do I give you a cookie good sir?

Comment: just an upvote on that comment is fine lol thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested by user Ruzihm the issue was that the crosshair was off-center. My blueprints were actually okay.
So for anyone looking see if your crosshair is in the center.